How to pairwise iterate over a type list and value list
I've got a typelist like
template <typename ...Types> struct type_list {};

and am looking for a way to iterate over pairs of elements from that type list and some value list from within a function like
template <typename ...Types, typename ...Values>
void f(type_list<Types...>, Values&&... values);

which is called like
template <int i, typename T> struct P {
    static constexpr int i = i;
    using type = T;
};
f(type_list<P<1, int>, P<3, double>>{}, 11, 12);

The lengths of the two lists are identical.
The types in the typelist are unrelated to the values in the valuelist.
Maybe there's a way to zip the two lists into some type/value pair and fold that afterwards?

Just write an expression that contains both of the tokens Types and Values.
Then put a ... after it in a context where such expressions can be expanded.
As an example:
template <typename ...Types, typename ...Values>
void f(type_list<Types...> list, Values&&... values) {

Make a tuple of Types, Values pairs:
  auto tup = std::tuple<std::pair<Types, Values>... >( {{}, std::forward<Values>(values)}... );

Invoke code on each Type, Value corresponding pair, using ... fold-expansion of the , operator and a lambda:
  auto operation = [&]<class Type, class Value>()->void{
    std::cout << typeid(Type).name() << "," << typeid<Value>.name() << "\n";
  };

  (operation.template operator()<Types, Values>(), ...);
}

or whatever.

Great! I added Value const& value to the operation definition parameters and values to the operation invocation arguments to get the values as well.

This can be done easily with fold expression:
template<typename Type, typename Value>
void iterate(Value&& value) {
  // ...
}

template <typename... Types, typename... Values>
void f(type_list<Types...>, Values&&... values) {
  (iterate<Types>(std::forward<Values>(values)), ...);
}

